# 2 python files simultaneously on Windows7 on python2.7. running the same code on Rpi,error: No file opened & no process termination

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, raspberry-pi2, execution

I am able to run two python files on my Windows 7  PC using following code:

Python Code:-

## Python Code in windows:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", 'C:\Python27/filess1.py'])

subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", 'C:\Python27/filess2.py'])
```

*#**filess1 & filess2** are the two python files, which i need to run simultaneously.Here 'C:\Python27/filess1.py' & C:\Python27/filess2.py' are file locations*

Whereas i copied the same two files on desktop of RASPBERRY Pi (with raspian), and write a new python code for simultaneous execution of these two files:

## Python code in Raspberry pi:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["python", '/home/pi/Desktop/filess1.py'])

subprocess.Popen(["python", '/home/pi/Desktop/filess2.py'])
```

Here i am finding :

```
**Infinite Loop with no termination:Any of the File didn't open.
```

whereas filess1 & filess2 is running independently on raspberry pi and meeting the purpose for which they are designed.
Please Help !

Comment: python.exe on a linux environment ? Just try with python

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code properly

Comment: @SnoozeTime on trying with 'python' instead of 'python.exe', there is no error on IDLE screen but there is no output .It is same  like as program enters an infinite loop

Comment: Well, this is related to what's inside the filess1 and filess2 scripts and not to what you wrote in your question =)

Comment: @SnoozeTime ,filess1 is a temperature sensor python code & filess2 is stepper motor code.Both are working very fine independently.Can you suggest me the possible edits in the codes.